# Add Cookie parameter in Swagger UI documentation with Springfox

Tags: spring, cookies, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I want to add a **@ApiImplicitParam** Springfox annotation to document on Swagger UI a **cookie**, required by the service

```
@GetMapping(value = "cookies")
public void methodA(
  @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    service.checkCookie(headers);  
}
```

I'll try doing

```
@GetMapping(value = "cookies")
public void methodA(
  @ApiImplicitParam(name="cookie", paramType = "header", type = "string") @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    service.checkCookie(headers);  
}
```

But in Swagger UI don't sent any cookie when I push on Execute button.

[image: Developer tools]

Cookie isn't sent, and return a **Bad Request 400** code. But If I execute the curl printed, I obtain an OK status.

```
curl -k -i -X GET "https://localhost:8080/cookies" -H "cookie: KEY=VALUE"
```

HTTP/1.1 200

Also try with *paramType* annotation value *cookie* like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "cookies")
public void methodA(
  @ApiImplicitParam(name="cookie", paramType = "cookie", type = "string") @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    service.checkCookie(headers);  
}
```

With the same 400 error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending cookie session ID with OpenAPI 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49272171/113116). Swagger UI cannot set the `Cookie` header because of browser security restrictions. More details here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1163