# Getting Cookie undefined in swagger api Cookie Authentication

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to access api through cookie auth in swagger api but getting cookie undefined in backend server, my server is running on a different port and API also running on different code:

```
 /leads:
    get:
      summary: Get all leads
      description: Retrieve a list of leads.
      security:
        - cookieAuth: []
      tags:
        - Leads
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful retrieval of leads
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  rows:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Lead"
                  count:
                    type: integer
        "400":
          description: Bad request
        "401":
          description: Unauthorized
        "500":
          description: Internal Server Error

components:
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: x-session
  schemas:
    Lead:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
        name:
          type: string
        total_deal_age:
          type: string
```

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49273653/113116